# Error:Could not concatenate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to return the function so that It would take a single word and convert it to Cow Latin. I am getting a concatenation error with my function.
(Python 3)

> If the word starts with a consonant then the Cow Latin version is
>   formed by moving the first letter to the end of the word and adding
>   the string "oo", eg, turtle -> urtletoo
>
> If the word starts with a non-consonant character then the Cow Latin
>   version is simply the English word followed by "moo", eg, egg ->
>   eggmoo and 121word -> 121wordmoo
>
> Consonants are defined as "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".

My function:

```
alpha = list("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")
def cow_latinify_word(word):
    if word[0].lower() in alpha:
        lista = list(word.lower())
        return lista[1:] + [lista[0]] + "oo"
    else:
        return word + "moo"

def cow_latinify_sentence(sentence):
    words = sentence.split();
    return [cow_latinify_word(word) for word in words]
```

When I run my function, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 11, in cow_latinify_sentence
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 5, in cow_latinify_word
builtins.TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenation is the `+` operator.

The error message explains the problem precisely: you're starting with a list, and trying to add a string to it in this line I'm assuming:

```
return lista[1:] + [lista[0]] + "oo"
```

Now what you want is to not add lists, but strings. You can do that by removing the `list()` around the `word.lower()` and removing the brackets around `lista[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are turning your words (strings) into lists:

```
lista = list(word.lower())
```

That does this:

```
my_str = "hello"
weirded_out = list(my_str)  # ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Then, you try to add "00" to a list, which causes an error:

```
return lista[1:] + [lista[0]] + "oo"
```

Either don't convert your word into a list (best option) or turn "00" into a list before you try to add them all together.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution you are converting `word` from string to a list consisting of the characters of the word (you are doing that for both `alpha` and `lista`. After doing so, the error you are getting simply states that you can't concatenate a list with a string. Your code will work when you remove the `list()` parts like this:

```
alpha = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
def cow_latinify_word(word):
    if word[0].lower() in alpha:
        lista = word.lower()
        return lista[1:] + lista[0] + "oo"
    else:
        return word + "moo"

def cow_latinify_sentence(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    return [cow_latinify_word(word) for word in words]
```

To better understand this you can check what is printed out in each case:

```
>>> print(list("hello"))
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']

>>> print("hello")
hello
```